# is it possible to use 3306 port (same port) in docker mysql running container as well as in windows 10 mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, docker, windows-10, tomcat7

I deploy my war file in tomcat 7 successfully and start tomcat using following command

```
docker run -it --rm -p 7008:8080 -v //d/docker_tomcat/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml:ro -v //d/docker_tomcat/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps:rw tomcat:7.0
```

when tomcat start it shows following error logs:-
AbandonedObjectPool is used   (org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool@9030ca2)
LogAbandoned: true
RemoveAbandoned: true
RemoveAbandonedTimeout: 90
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

**i think that above error means that database studentdb is not accessible**

here is my hibernate.properties file:-

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=root
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://10.0.75.x<ip of docker>:3306/studentdb?autoreconnect=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
show_sql=false
hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=false
hibernate.dbcp.testOnBorrow=true
hibernate.dbcp.validationQuery=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
hibernate.dbcp.testOnReturn=false
hibernate.dbcp.maxWait=2000
hibernate.dbcp.testWhileIdle=true
hibernate.dbcp.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
hibernate.dbcp.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=300000
hibernate.dbcp.numTestsPerEvictionRun=5
hibernate.dbcp.removeAbandoned=true
hibernate.dbcp.removeAbandonedTimeout=90
hibernate.dbcp.logAbandoned=true
```

> i think there may be error in hibernate.connection.url property of
>   hibernate.properties file.

and also doubt is it becuase my windows 10 uses port 3306 for mysql as well as docker also uses port 3306 for mysql. if is it problem then how can i change port of mysql container running in docker with some different port

Comment: Are you sure about database name `studentdb` ? Any case sensitive letters?

Comment: yes database name studentdb. all letters in small case

Answer (score 1):

Use following command to forward your local port to docker container port

`docker run -p <LOCAL-PORT>:3306 <mysql-image-name>`